# Togglegroup for buttons in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following code which is a grouping of buttons in javafx:

```
ToggleGroup groupLevelQ = new ToggleGroup();

    class MyLevelButton extends ToggleButton {
        public MyLevelButton(String name) {
            super(name);
            setPrefWidth(50.0);
            setPrefHeight(50.0);
            setStyle("-fx-font: 20 cornerstone; -fx-base: #17499F;");
            setToggleGroup(groupLevelQ);
        }
    }

    oneLevelButton = new MyLevelButton("1");
    twoLevelButton = new MyLevelButton("2");
    threeLevelButton = new MyLevelButton("3");
    fourLevelButton = new MyLevelButton("4");
    fiveLevelButton = new MyLevelButton("5");
    sixLevelButton = new MyLevelButton("6");
    sevenLevelButton = new MyLevelButton("7");
    eightLevelButton = new MyLevelButton("8");
    nineLevelButton = new MyLevelButton("9");

    oneLevelButton.setUserData("1");
    twoLevelButton.setUserData("2");
    threeLevelButton.setUserData("3");
    fourLevelButton.setUserData("4");
    fiveLevelButton.setUserData("5");
    sixLevelButton.setUserData("6");
    sevenLevelButton.setUserData("7");
    eightLevelButton.setUserData("8");
    nineLevelButton.setUserData("9");

    groupLevelQ.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov, Toggle toggle, Toggle new_toggle) {
            if (new_toggle != null) {
                textLevelQ = (String) groupLevelQ.getSelectedToggle().getUserData();
            }

        }
    });

    addQButtonPane.add(oneLevelButton, 1, 9);
    addQButtonPane.add(twoLevelButton, 2, 9);
    addQButtonPane.add(threeLevelButton, 3, 9);
    addQButtonPane.add(fourLevelButton, 4, 9);
    addQButtonPane.add(fiveLevelButton, 5, 9);
    addQButtonPane.add(sixLevelButton, 6, 9);
    addQButtonPane.add(sevenLevelButton, 7, 9);
    addQButtonPane.add(eightLevelButton, 8, 9);
    addQButtonPane.add(nineLevelButton, 9, 9);
```

In fact I am creating buttons and I add them in a GridPane. I am trying to figure out how can I define the distance between the buttons. Basically as they are right now they have a default distance them and I want to change that.

EDIT:

```
addQButtonPane = new GridPane();
    addQButtonPane.setHgap(10);
    addQButtonPane.setVgap(10);
    addQButtonPane.setPadding(new Insets(0, 50, 0, 50));
    addQButtonPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #95CBE5;");
```

This is the way that my gridpane is formatted. But still I want to change this formation just for the specific mentioned buttons.

**EDIT2:**

[image]

Comment: you should define the buttons in an FXML and control the layout using CSS

Comment: I dont have knowledge in javafx and I have to modify the code of the project. It doesn't contain a FXML, everything is in the source code. Can I create a fxml file and a css file seperately?

Comment: if that's real live code then leave the project as soon as you can. If you can't (or don't want) turn it into better code by refactoring it!

Comment: Basically this is my task, to refactor it. But what is the first thing that I should do? To create a new FXML and CSS files?

Comment: There's no need to use FXML if you don't want; this can all be done in Java if you prefer. Contrary to other comments here, CSS is (for the most part) **not** used for layout in JavaFX: CSS is used for *style*, and either FXML or Java are used for layout. Obviously you can refactor this code considerably to reduce the repetition; however I think your question is actually about layout. How is the grid pane defined and configured and how specifically do you want to change the way it behaves?

Comment: @JoseRamon *"But what is the first thing that I should do? To create a new FXML and CSS files?"* IMHO that's a good start. separate the layout from the logic. The layout goes into FXML and CSS and the logic goes into a controller class. Unfotinately you might have to create the latter from scratch since what you posted is almost unusable. You should also consider using a Table to avoid this bunch of almost equal button instances.

Comment: @James_D: *"There's no need to use FXML"* right, there is no need to use a screwdriver to get a screw into a wall, a hammer will do too! - What do you think at which time someone should start doing things better? IMHO it's **now**!

Comment: @TimothyTruckle You're assuming FXML is better. I think it's just an option. As long as you have good separation between data and presentation, and some degree of separation within the separation between layout and logic, then FXML vs Java is just a consumer choice.

Comment: I cant understand what is the difference betwwen fxml and css. Why to have them both?

Comment: @JoseRamon FXML is an option to do the layout (positioning, which components are grouped with which, and so on). CSS is used for style (colors, fonts, etc).

Comment: *"This is the way that my gridpane is formatted. But still I want to change this formation just for the specific mentioned buttons."* You haven't mentioned any buttons. The buttons seem to be the only contents of the `Gridpane`! Are you looking for [margins](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setMargin-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.geometry.Insets-)???

Comment: Ok got it so every gripane and toggle groups should be in FXML.

Comment: the FXML defined the structure of your Frame. The CSS defines colors and spacing. You can easily change the colors and spaces by simply replacing the CSS.

Comment: I would argue it's just as valid to do them in Java as it is in FXML. This seems like an orthogonal argument to your actual question. Please explain *how* you want the buttons to be different....

Comment: @fabian check the code I add in the gridPane addQButtonPane MyLevelButton buttons.

Comment: I want to them to be closer each other than the other objects of gridPane.

Comment: @JoseRamon But they are in a grid: that's what a gridpane does... So they can't be closer than other components in the grid as they have been placed in columns and rows along with those other components (which you haven't shown). Can you be more specific? Perhaps post some code (not all 10 rows please) and some screenshots (how it looks, how you want it to look...)?

Comment: I just add a pic of how it look, my code with the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the kind of layout you're trying to achieve could be better achieved by placing `HBox`es containing the options and `Text` elements inside a `VBox`.

But if you're looking for a way to "take the buttons out of the usual layout", you could simply place them inside a `HBox` use a `columnSpan` that covers all remaining columns:

```
double buttonDistance = ...
int gridPaneColumnCount = ...
HBox buttonBox = new HBox(buttonDistance,
    oneLevelButton,
    twoLevelButton,
    threeLevelButton,
    fourLevelButton,
    fiveLevelButton,
    sixLevelButton,
    sevenLevelButton,
    eightLevelButton,
    nineLevelButton);

addQButtonPane.add(buttonBox, 1, 9, gridPaneColumnCount-1, 1);
```

Comment: That did the trick. However I am interesting in finding if I can put everything on FXML and CSS. Can I create files that do that things?

Comment: @JoseRamon fxml can be used to create most scenes you could also create from java code. From css however you cannot assign static properties, so it's impossible to set column spans. Furthermore you cannot use CSS to make the `GridPane`'s layout algorithm behave in a different way that would suit your needs, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html  / https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html